# Inserting new rows in a table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 613 rows already. When I want to insert new rows from another table, the new rows are updated correctly in terms of the respective column but the ID column that is IDENTITY shows random numbers after 613. Like it doesn't update according to the count for new rows that are inserted.

I'm using Insert into Select statement.

Comment: Please show your insert statement and create table script.

Comment: The ID column, is it a sequence?

Comment: `IDENTITY` means the number always increases. It doesn't have *anything* to do with counts. If you add 1000 rows and then delete them, it won't start from 1, it will continue from 1001 onwards. If it didn't it wouldn't be an *identity*, it would only be a row-number that can't identify anything

Comment: Post your code. There's nothing wrong with IDENTITY, it's been in use for over 20 years. Either the code doesn't do what you think it does, or there is a misunderstanding on what IDENTITY is

Comment: If you want to keep in table_A some number from table_B, you need to store in table_A in a field that is NOT identity, no matter if that number is identity in table_B.

Comment: I guess there was bit of misunderstanding with IDENTITY. Thank you for clearing that out. 
Though, another problem is that when I add new rows, they get added randomly and in between the existing rows.